# Capture the call that analytics.js makes after it is loaded using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, phantomjs

I have been trying to Capture the call that analytics.js makes after it is loaded in phantomjs headless browser.
The problem with this is that, analytics.js load after the page completely loads. So, its getting difficult to track analytics.js calls.
The code which I have tried till now is:

```
var url = "http://www.alexandani.com/necklaces/sand-dollar-expandable-necklace.html";
var auditlinks = {"www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js": 6, "metrics.alexandani.com": 9, "www.google-analytics.com/collect": 7};
var block_request = 1;
var execution_timeout = 40000;
var resource_timeout = 50000;
var inactivity_timeout = 50000;
var user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.0 Safari/534.34";

var page_http_status_target_url = url;
var page_http_status = null;

var inactivity_timeout_check_period = 100;

var requests = new Array();
var auditlink_urls = Object.keys(auditlinks);


function print(obj){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function create_url_cleaner(){
    var rx_match_protocol = /^(http|https):\/\//i;
    var rx_match_query_params = /\/*\?.*/i;

    function clean_url(url){
        return (
            (url.replace(rx_match_protocol, ''))
            .replace(rx_match_query_params, '')
        );
    }

    return clean_url;
}



function exit(exit_reason){

    console.log(requests);
    print({
        'requests': requests,
        'exit_reason': exit_reason,

        // Returning http status as an integer makes little sense to me.
        'http_status': (page_http_status === null)
                       ? null : page_http_status.toString(),
    });
    phantom.exit(0);
}



function start_exec_time_limiter(execution_timeout){
    setTimeout(
        function (){
            console.log('hi');
            exit("EXEC_TIMEOUT");
        },
        execution_timeout
    );
}



function start_inactivity_tracker(
    inactivity_timeout,
    inactivity_timeout_check_period
){
    var last_activity_time = Date.now();

    function register_activity(){
        last_activity_time = Date.now();
    }

    function check_inactivity(){
        var now = Date.now();

        if (now - last_activity_time > inactivity_timeout){
            exit("INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT")
        }
    }

    setInterval(check_inactivity, inactivity_timeout_check_period);
    return register_activity;
}



start_exec_time_limiter(execution_timeout);

var clean_url = create_url_cleaner();
var register_activity = start_inactivity_tracker(
    inactivity_timeout, inactivity_timeout_check_period);


var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = user_agent;
page.settings.resourceTimeout = resource_timeout;
//page.injectJs('wait.js');
page.onError = function (msg, stack){
    // Ignore errors in the webpage context.
}

page.onResourceReceived = function (response){
    register_activity();

    if (response.url == page_http_status_target_url){
        if (response.redirectURL){
            page_http_status_target_url = response.redirectURL;
        }
        else {
            page_http_status = response.status;
            page_http_status_target_url = null;
        }
    }
}

page.onResourceRequested = function (requestData, request){
    register_activity();
    var timestamp = Date.now();

    var url = requestData["url"];
    var bare_url = clean_url(url);

    for (var k in auditlink_urls){
        var alurl = auditlink_urls[k];

        if (bare_url.indexOf(alurl) === 0){
            requests[requests.length] = [url, auditlinks[alurl], timestamp];

            if (block_request === true){
                request.abort();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

}

page.open(url);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: So if understand you correctly, you simply want probably mimified JavaScript content of analytics.js. I don't see where you try to download it. Instead you included a bunch of unrelated stuff.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Actually I need to Capture the call that analytics.js makes after it is loaded

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have just updated the question, please reply now

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to load analytics.js at all in PhantomJS? If all you want to do is test that the calls to `ga()` are what you'd expect, just stub out the `ga()` function and assert that the calls it receives are what you'd expect.

In fact, the [analytics.js snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#snippet) itself is essentially just a stub that stores the calls it receives on its `q` property while it waits for the full library to download.

If you don't download the analytics.js script, that `ga.q` will always be inspectable.